# Change date format in R using as.Date

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to change date format in the data frame for date columns. My date column is in format `Mar 13 2007 01:05:123AM`. Now this date format values are same except day change and time remains same. So I was thinking to change it to format as `Mar 13 2007`.

I tried the following code:

```
df <- read.csv("mydata.csv")
df$collectdate <- format(as.Date(df$collectdate,"%b %d %Y"))
```

but it gives error saying "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format". What can I try next?

Comment: It looks like the error is R not recognizing what format your date column is in.

Comment: @user449355  It is better to post some example data using `dput` ie. `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: What is your locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
  date <- "Mar 13 2007 01:05:123AM"

 gsub("(.*)(?=\\s\\d{2}:).*", "\\1", date, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "Mar 13 2007"
```

For the `as.Date`, it didn't show any errors.

```
 format(as.Date(date,"%b %d %Y"), "%b %d %Y")
 #[1] "Mar 13 2007
```